# Vampire book series

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

I am a little fuzzy on what happens in which book but this is what I know:
There is a teenage girl with a best friend (Mel maybe), a few days before her birthday (16th?) family friends come back to town and she finds out she is a half vampire and will transform on her birthday.

I think her boyfriend's name is Kellan and I know that she meets three vampire brothers when working for the vampire council, one of their names is Kai. She is on a mission to stop the hunters after both of her parents are killed by them.

Before her transformation she was fairly curvy and her aunt took her to buy a new wardrobe afterwards because she lost so much weight. One of the council leaders name is Auggy.

Comment: Please add in as much information as you remember by [edit]ing the question. Note the more you add the more likely it is someone will find this for you. Anything on the plot or character descriptions is most likely to help but when you read this, how old they are, etc. will also help a lot. For example, what was she doing whilst working for the vampire council? And welcome to the site!

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

[Diary of a Vampeen](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13481209-diary-of-a-vampeen) by Christin Lovell. It is the first book of her [Vamp Chronicles series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/74777-vamp-chronicles) that currently runs to seven books and two novellas.

[image: Diary of a Vampeen]

> Imagine living a human charade for fifteen years and never knowing it. Imagine being provided less than a week to learn and accept your family’s true heritage before it overtook you. Alexa Jackson, Lexi, is abruptly thrown onto this roller coaster and quickly learns that she can’t change fate, regardless of how many lifetimes she is given. She will be transformed into a vampeen on her sixteenth birthday, she will be called upon to fulfill a greater destiny within the dangerous world of vampires, and she will have to risk heartbreak and rejection if she ever wants a chance at love with Kellan, whether she likes it or not.

Lexi's best friend is indeed *Mel*. I don't think we ever learn her surname - skimming the first couple of chapters she is always just referred to as "Mel". The only mention I can find of the new wardrobe is when Kellan is describing the transformation to Lexi:

> “You sleep through everything. It’s like when you have surgery, the anesthesia makes you sleep deep enough to ignore the pain,” he explained. “After, when you wake up, it is shocking at first. Everything is intensified. You hear every pin drop and smell every daisy three yards down, but you adjust after a few days. You’ll feel weird. It’s almost like an out-of-body experience in the beginning. You’ll have to get to know your new figure and lifestyle. You’ll have to buy a new wardrobe.

I cannot find any mention of *Kai* or *Auggy*, but I only have the first book and they may be in later books.